# jd gui doesnt open on win10

Tags: java, crash, jd-gui

i am trying to open jd gui. i am using .jar version for windows. when i double click the jar a coffe icon appears at screen, but nothing else happens. i tried reinstalling java before, but same result. btw, i can run my other executable jar files properly. and then i tried to run it via command prompt. thats what i got as error report

```
C:\Users\HP\Desktop>java -jar jd-gui.jar
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3$1 (file:/C:/Users/HP/Desktop/jd-gui.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader(jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader,jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath) accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.loader" to unnamed module @6321e813
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor$1.run(CachedConstructor.java:41)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.<init>(CachedConstructor.java:39)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$2.initValue(CachedClass.java:76)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$2.initValue(CachedClass.java:66)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:33)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass.getConstructors(CachedClass.java:265)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.<init>(MetaClassImpl.java:215)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.<init>(MetaClassImpl.java:225)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.createNormalMetaClass(MetaClassRegistry.java:168)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.createWithCustomLookup(MetaClassRegistry.java:158)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.create(MetaClassRegistry.java:141)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:250)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:292)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:259)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getMetaClass(InvokerHelper.java:868)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createPojoSite(CallSiteArray.java:122)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(CallSiteArray.java:163)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
        at org.jd.gui.view.MainDescription.run(MainDescription.groovy:170)
        at groovy.util.FactoryBuilderSupport.build(FactoryBuilderSupport.java:1169)
        at groovy.util.FactoryBuilderSupport.build(FactoryBuilderSupport.java:1152)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:382)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1017)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:161)
        at org.jd.gui.view.MainView$_closure1.doCall(MainView.groovy:69)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:292)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1017)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1017)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:417)
        at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
        at groovy.swing.SwingBuilder$_edt_closure1.doCall(SwingBuilder.groovy:333)
        at groovy.swing.SwingBuilder$_edt_closure1.doCall(SwingBuilder.groovy)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:292)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1017)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:417)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:504)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$600(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

when i downloaded it, i went to the features of file and then removed the tick for"this is downloaded from internet this can harm etc." i mean there isnt any security blockings too. can someone help please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run decompiler under Java 8. Change your JAVA_HOME to point to Java 8 or older. And it will work.

Comment: is oracle kidding me. i installed java 10 but it almost works nowhere. doesnt work at minecraft. eclipse recognizes it as 1.4 . it cant run jd- gui. should i install java 8 back then

Comment: Since java8 is last long term supported version until 11 is out in September i would suggest using it if you do not need some of the features of 9 and 10 explicitly. Never saw that problem with eclipse before, in IntelliJ its working fine.